# Show that distribution doesn't belong to Exponential Family

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be distributed by the following density function
$$f_X(x;\gamma)=\frac{1}{\pi((x-\gamma)^2+1)}, \ \ \ \ \ x,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$$
Then we want to show that $\{f_X(x;\gamma): \gamma\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is not a one dimensional exponential family.

We have that if there exists $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+,
\eta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f_X(x;\gamma)=h(x)g(\gamma)\exp(\eta(\gamma)T(x))$$
then $\{f_X(x;\gamma): \gamma\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a one dimensional exponential family.

But I can't seem to show that this distribution doesn't belong to the exponential family.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The density in question is that of a Cauchy random variable with location $\gamma$. As you correctly noted, it is not possible to express its density in the form of an exponential family.

Indeed,

$$
f(x;\gamma) = (1/\pi)\exp(-\log(1+(x-\gamma)^2)),
$$

and since $\log(1+(x-\gamma)^2)$ cannot be written as a product of a function of $\gamma$ times a function of $x$, we conclude that $f$ does not belong to the exponential family.